# Wordpress - Como incluir novos campos na tabela de usuários?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Quero incluir os seguintes campos no cadastro dos usuários registrados no meu blog: IBGE, Município e UF.

Como faço para incluir esses campos e posteriormente, acessá-los em uma página específica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tabela `wp_user_meta`. Wordpress gerencia a base de dados para você de forma que não é preciso e nem aconselhável alterar a estrutura de tabelas existentes. Para associar uma nova informação ao usuário use:

```
$userId = get_current_user_id();
$nomeCampo = 'uf';
$valor = 'SP';
update_user_meta($userId, $nomeCampo, $valor);
```

A documentação define a função da seguinte [forma](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/):

```
update_user_meta(int $user_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, mixed $prev_value = '');
```

Para resgatar a informação salva em outro lugar use:

```
$userId = get_current_user_id();
$nomeCampo = 'uf';
get_user_meta($userId, $nomeCampo);
```

A documentação define a função da seguinte [forma](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/):

```
get_user_meta(int $user_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Deve servir. Só alterar o código, trocando as redes sociais para sua necessidade http://www.escolawp.com/2011/12/como-adicionar-mais-campos-no-perfil-de-usuarios-do-wordpress/

Na functions.php:

```
<?php  function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<table class="form-table">
  <tr>
    <th><label for="ibge">IBGE</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="ibgeuser" id="ibgeuser" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'ibgeuser', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
      <br />
      <span class="description">IBGE</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><label for="municipiouser">Município</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="municipiouser" id="municipiouser" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'municipiouser', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
      <br />
      <span class="description">Município</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><label for="ufuser">UF</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="ufuser" id="ufuser" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'ufuser', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
      <br />
      <span class="description">UF</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Para salvar os dados inseridos pelo usuário:

```
<?php
// GUARDAR E MANTER INFO DOS CAMPOS
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'ibgeuser', $_POST['ibgeuser'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'municipiouser', $_POST['municipiouser'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'ufuser', $_POST['ufuser'] );
} ?>
```

Para usar as informações do db, `<?php echo $curauth->ibgeuser; ?>` e assim por diante.

Comment: É interessante que o conteúdo principal da publicação esteja no site e não em links externos. Coloque o que você viu no link em sua resposta.